# ADF4106 RF input range

Tags: clock, pll, vco

I am trying to design PLL for generating 122.8MHz from 40 MHz REFIN. I am following the [CN0290 EVM](https://www.analog.com/media/en/reference-design-documentation/reference-designs/CN0290.pdf) reference for design. As you can see, in the EVM REF_INPUT is of 10MHz and 100MHz frequency is being generated by using VCXO, but in the datasheet of [ADF4106](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADF4106.pdf) RF_INPUT is mentioned in the range of 500MHz - 6GHz.

Since the EVM uses ADCLK Clock buffers to compensate for the slew at the lower frequencies.

Can I use a VCO in the place of VCXO to generate 122.8MHz out of 40MHz REF_Input?

Answer (score 0):

You can use RF IN below 500MHz as long as you meet the slew rate spec.  If you are driving the RF IN from the ADCLK925 as shown in the app note you should be fine.  You can use a VCO as long as the phase noise is adequate for your application.

As a general rule, keep the phase detector frequency as high as possible, probably 400kHz for 122.8MHz (or 320kHz if you are after 122.88MHz)

Comment: I have a follow-up question, once the desired frequency is generated and PLL is locked and if I remove the REF_IN, still PLL will be generating the frequency?

Comment: If a PLL, the VCO always runs and produces an output frequency.  When you provide REF_IN, the PLL should lock and the tuning voltage to the VCO will settle on a value that makes the frequency correct \$(F_{vco} = \frac{N}{R} F_{ref})\$ and is phase locked to the reference.  When you remove REF_IN, the VCO frequency will change, probably drop to the lowest it can as the PLL tries to make it the same as REF_IN (which is zero).